# Spring CrudRepository: why to invent a new generic type S

Tags: java, spring, generics

Could you please give me a hint **why in CrudRepository interface in the "save" method there is a new generic type "S" is invented**. (see [org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html))

Here is an extraction for CrudRepository class:

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
         extends Repository<T, ID> {
    /**
     * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further
     * operations as the save operation might have changed the
     * entity instance completely.
     * 
     * @param entity
     * @return the saved entity
     */
     <S extends T> S save(S entity);

     ...

     /**
      * Deletes a given entity.
      * 
      * @param entity
      * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given entity is (@literal null}.
      */
      void delete(T entity);
}
```

Please note, in the second method "delete" the same entity has type T.
The method "save" says it returns an object of type "S". So this is impossible to implement the method "save" say like this:

```
@Override
public <S extends MyType> S save(S entity) {
    save(entity);
    return findOne(entity.getMyTypeId()); // Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyType to S
}
```

The other question is how to implement the method "save" better?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose is that generally, Spring `*Repository` interfaces are implemented automatically by Spring Data and not by hand, and that it's convenient to know that you'll get the same type of object back out of the `save` operation as you put in. Especially for document-oriented data stores, it's not unusual to see subclasses persisted in the same repository as superclasses, and using `S extends T` as the parameter and return type ensures that you can keep working with the persisted object with the same interface you would have before saving it.

Comment: **chrylis**, thank you! What if I like this interface CrudRepository and going to use this as a contract for my *RepositoryImpl. How to implement the method "save" better?

Answer (score 0):

Seems one of implementation for save can be:

```
@Override
public <S extends MyType> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {
    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();
    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }
    return result;
}
```