# What does it mean <S extends T> save (S entity); in Spring Repository?

Tags: java, spring, generics, repository, spring-data

In Spring Data project the CrudRepository provides sophisticated CRUD functionality for the entity class that is being managed.

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
extends Repository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    T findOne(ID primaryKey);

    Iterable<T> findAll();

    Long count();

    void delete(T entity);

    boolean exists(ID primaryKey);

    // … more functionality omitted.
}
```

In general, I know what "S extends T" means, i.e. that S, the return type of save operation, must be subtype of T. Why is it necessary to add such as constraint? I think that would be fine doing something like this:

```
T save (T entity);
```

As in

```
void delete(T entity);
```

I've googled to find more help and I've figured out following question on stackoverflow itself but it isn't really clear for me:

[Spring CrudRepository: why to invent a new generic type S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346036/spring-crudrepository-why-to-invent-a-new-generic-type-s)

thank you.

Comment: I think you are right. `S` is redundant, and the signature design is a mistake.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you were to have it as

```
T save (T entity);
```

Then the only variable you could assign the result to would have to be of type `T`.

So, if you have a `CrudRepository<Animal,AnimalID> repository`, and you have

```
Dog dog = getDog();
Dog savedDog = repository.save(dog);
```

You'd get a compile error - you can't assign the result to `Dog`, as it has to be of type `T`, in this case, `Animal`.

You'd need to check if the returned value was indeed of type `Dog`, and if so, cast it to `Dog` to put it in `savedDog`.

With the declaration as it is, it means that you can assign it to a variable of the same type as the original argument, as type resolution will allow that.

The declaration itself doesn't specify how the non-animal parts of the dog are saved if at all. All it does is allow assigning the result back to a `Dog` if it was originally a `Dog`.

Answer (score 1):

It's an example of an Upper Bound for the save Method whereas S in the entity a programmer may wish to persist using an implementation of CrudRepository.
UpperBounds restricts the type of object that can be passed to the save method and T in this case is the instance type of Entities that are typically managed by CrudRepository meaning only the child or implementation of those Entities can be used as S.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991711/inferred-type-does-not-conform-to-upper-bounds-hotelrepository-savebookings) highlighted the error but this [one](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/error-method-save-in-interface-crudrepositorytid-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types-coursessavebunchofcourses) showed the error description which clearly tells the story.