# What does <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) mean

Tags: java

Its in the `JpaRepository`

```
    /*
 * Copyright 2008-2016 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.data.jpa.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor;

/**
 * JPA specific extension of {@link org.springframework.data.repository.Repository}.
 *
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 * @author Christoph Strobl
 * @author Mark Paluch
 */
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface JpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#findAll()
     */
    List<T> findAll();

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository#findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Sort)
     */
    List<T> findAll(Sort sort);

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#findAll(java.lang.Iterable)
     */
    List<T> findAll(Iterable<ID> ids);

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#save(java.lang.Iterable)
     */
    <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);

    /**
     * Flushes all pending changes to the database.
     */
    void flush();

    /**
     * Saves an entity and flushes changes instantly.
     * 
     * @param entity
     * @return the saved entity
     */
    <S extends T> S saveAndFlush(S entity);

    /**
     * Deletes the given entities in a batch which means it will create a single {@link Query}. Assume that we will clear
     * the {@link javax.persistence.EntityManager} after the call.
     * 
     * @param entities
     */
    void deleteInBatch(Iterable<T> entities);

    /**
     * Deletes all entities in a batch call.
     */
    void deleteAllInBatch();

    /**
     * Returns a reference to the entity with the given identifier.
     * 
     * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
     * @return a reference to the entity with the given identifier.
     * @see EntityManager#getReference(Class, Object)
     */
    T getOne(ID id);

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor#findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Example)
     */
    @Override
    <S extends T> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example);

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor#findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Example, org.springframework.data.domain.Sort)
     */
    @Override
    <S extends T> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Sort sort);

}
```

[image]

I don't understand in combination, what this `save` ... defination is about? and the SO question answered here [What does it mean <S extends T> save (S entity); in Spring Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960743/what-does-it-mean-s-extends-t-save-s-entity-in-spring-repository) was very confusing as its example with Both using T and confused me more with having `Dog` involved....

Would anyone able to explain the whole phrase piece by piece and with maybe a small example when needed?

Basically the use case is when I extended the JpaRepository. I wonder what exactly I can pass into this `.save` function, and by looking at this function defination here, I have no idea and not sure how to proceed to understand it better without have to digging through a lot more documentation for java and blog posts.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pasted the code, not sure how much difference it can make though?

Comment: It's not clear what you didn't understand about the other answer, or why you think another answer would be more helpful. As it stands, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @shmosel good point... I dont understand the combination itself and what does it entail. hope that answer your confusion?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @shmosel fair enough. I updated with my situation.

Comment: Have a look at [Generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

Comment: It means you can pass an `Iterable` of any subtype of `T` and get back a `List` of the same type.

Comment: Honestly - I feel like the other answer you had shared answers it pretty concisely.  It makes more sense once you understand [how bounded generics behave](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Comment: I assume that in the answer referred to `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`, although I don't think that is explicitly stated. Does that clarify at all?

Comment: the useful part is that :
"The declaration itself doesn't specify how the non-animal parts of the dog are saved if at all. All it does is allow assigning the result back to a Dog if it was originally a Dog."

What does that mean precisely ?
case 1: `T save(T entity)`
case 2: `<S extends T> S save(S entity)`

if you have `A` a subclass of `T` and `A foo = new A()`, you can do `save(foo)` in both cases, ok.
but if you try `A savedFoo = saved(foo)` in case 1 it will not compile whereas in case 2 it will