# inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s) hotelRepository.save(bookings) underlined

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have some problems with generics in Repository interfase and in DatabaseSeeder
When I launch server appears error "inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)" and hotelRepository.save(bookings) underlined. Could somebody help me to solve tis issue?

Entity

```
@Entity
public class HotelBooking {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;
private String hotelName;
private double pricePerNight;
private int nbOfNights;

public HotelBooking(String hotelName, double pricePerNight, int nbOfNights){
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
    this.pricePerNight = pricePerNight;
    this.nbOfNights = nbOfNights;
}


public HotelBooking() {
}

public String getHotelName() {
    return hotelName;
}

public double getPricePerNight() {
    return pricePerNight;
}

public int getNbOfNights() {
    return nbOfNights;
}

public void setHotelName(String hotelName) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
}

public void setPricePerNight(double pricePerNight) {
    this.pricePerNight = pricePerNight;
}

public void setNbOfNights(int nbOfNights) {
    this.nbOfNights = nbOfNights;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Controller

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value = "/bookings")
 public class HotelController {

HotelRepository hotelRepository;

@Autowired
public HotelController(HotelRepository hotelRepository){
    this.hotelRepository = hotelRepository;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<HotelBooking> getAll(){
    return hotelRepository.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/affordable/{price}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<HotelBooking> getAffordable(@PathVariable double price){
  return hotelRepository.findByPricePerNightLessThan(price);
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<HotelBooking> create(@RequestBody HotelBooking hotelBooking){
   hotelRepository.save(hotelBooking);
    return hotelRepository.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<HotelBooking> remove(@PathVariable Long id){
    hotelRepository.deleteById(id);
    return hotelRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

Component  class

```
@Component
public class DatabaseSeeder implements CommandLineRunner {

private HotelRepository hotelRepository;

@Autowired
public DatabaseSeeder(HotelRepository hotelRepository){
    this.hotelRepository = hotelRepository;
}

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
       List<HotelBooking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Marriot", 200.5, 3));
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Ibis", 300.5, 4));
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Novotel", 100.5, 1));
        hotelRepository.save(bookings);
}
}
```

Repository class

```
@Repository
public interface HotelRepository extends JpaRepository<HotelBooking, Long> {

    List<HotelBooking> findByPricePerNightLessThan(double price);


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `hotelRepository.saveAll(bookings);` instead of `hotelRepository.save(bookings);`

Comment: Thanks, a lot for your help, could you explain, please, in what cases may I use save() ?

Comment: save() method is to save a single instance of an entity.

Comment: [K. Siva Prasad Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755932/k-siva-prasad-reddy) Thanks a lot your advice helped me

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition the the previous answer:
Your code should work if you use spring-boot 1.5 but in 2.0 the implementation of the API of the spring data CrudRepository is changed and now you should use saveAll to save iterables.

You should also consider configuring your batch requests if you want to save a greater amount of data in one saveAll request.
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/