# Lombok builder not producing builder method, inferred type does not conform to upper bound

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I was following this video tutorial to learn about Spring a bit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-f-7l8X716k

I all went well up untill an `@Builder` annotation got introduced.

When trying to use it, my build fails with the following message:

> [ERROR]
>   ...spring/library/src/main/java/com/demo/LibraryApplication.java:[23,33]
>   method save in interface
>   org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository cannot be
>   applied to given types;   required: S   found:
>   com.demo.domain.Book.BookBuilder   reason: inferred type does not
>   conform to upper bound(s)
>       inferred: com.demo.domain.Book.BookBuilder
>       upper bound(s): com.demo.domain.Book

The output talks of `BookBuilder` but nothing like that shows up in autocomplete.

I found this question: [inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s) hotelRepository.save(bookings) underlined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991711/inferred-type-does-not-conform-to-upper-bounds-hotelrepository-savebookings)

But the offered solution there changes nothing.

What's going wrong here?

EDIT: I worked with Eclipse STS

Looking at the effective POM, I'm seeing:

- Lombok 1.16.22
- Everytthing Spring related is 2.0.6.RELEASE

The code simply looks like this:

Book.java:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title, isbn;
}
```

BookRepository.java:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "books", collectionResourceRel = "books")
public interface BookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, Long> {

}
```

LibraryApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraryApplication {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepo;

    @Component
    class DataSetup implements ApplicationRunner {
        @Override
        public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
            bookRepo.save(Book.builder());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LibraryApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code sample and more information about lombok/spring/spring data/boot versions.

Comment: a BookBuilder is not a Book. when you call .build() on an instance of BookBuilder, that's when you get a Book

Comment: @Chlebik Updated question with source code and version info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Book.builder return an `BookBuilder` where you can set attribute if you want to create a Book you should just do something like :

```
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    bookRepo.save(Book.builder().build());
}
```

you can look at the [lombok builder documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)

Comment: I just did `mvn clean compile`, then started it in STS and it worked with a filled out Book instance. Going to Project-Clean and then running from STS makes it fail. Doing `mvn clean compile` and then running from STS does work... yet still underlines builder() in red... I can go to localhost:8080/books and my filled in book is there... Still showing red in the editor... Weird.

Comment: Not the same trouble, but you should look at : https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse, I think you have bad config of STS form the lombok plugin. (Or no plugin ? )

Comment: I tried installing it by running the jar, but it keeps saying it can't detect an IDE.